# Adjust size of UIView inside UIScrollView according to its content

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have such layout hierarchy inside of the root `UIView` (see the picture):
`UIScrollView` -> `UIView` -> `UITextView`

I change the size of the `UIScrollView` view dynamically in the code on `UITextView`.`textViewDidChange`.
I have a constraint for `UIView.bottom` that is equal to `Superview.bottom` (`UIScrollView`).
Everything works until the `UITextView` view fits one screen.

How to adjust `UIView` programmatically to be equal to the `UITextView` size.

[image]

Comment: can you create a constraint for this, for example UIView size to be  X and on textViewDidChange use constraint.constant = newSize

Comment: It works (except some situations), but I get an error: "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." https://www.pastiebin.com/5d4d7d5d311b1

Comment: can you remove the constraint  for  vertical centers of the scrollView and the view

Comment: If you have a `UITextView` inside a `UIScrollView` disable scrolling on the text view. It will then auto-size its height based on the text. Use constraints just like any other view (or, for example, a `UILabel` with number of rows set to zero).

Comment: @m1sh0, I get error in UIBuilder - Need constraints for: Y position or height

Comment: @DonMag, I have UITextView (with disabled scrolling) inside UIView that is inside UIScrollView.

Comment: the scroll view or the view?

Comment: @m1sh0, I deleted UIView.centerY = UIScrollView.centerY, and got that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is:

- constrain the `UITextView` top / leading / trailing to its superview (the `UIView`)
- constrain the `UITextView` **bottom** to its superview bottom (the `UIView`), with `>=`
- constrain the `UIView` top / bottom / leading / trailing to its superview (the `UIScrollView`)
- constrain the `UIView` width and height equal to width and height of its superview (the `UIScrollView`)
- edit the height constraint and set `Priority: 250`

This will allow the text view to grow / shrink vertically based on its content. The `UIView` will remain at the height of the scroll view, until the text view grows too tall to fit. At that point, the low Priority will allow the bottom edge of the `UIView` to be "pushed down" as the text view grows.

Here's the layout in storyboard:

[image]

at runtime:

[image]

with lots of text and scrolled up:

[image]

And here's the source of the Storyboard (NO code needed - just the storyboard):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14490.70" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="VM1-mg-1mG">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14490.49"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="jpE-FH-8e8">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="VM1-mg-1mG" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="yS7-gh-XNz">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gBx-Cd-lhB">
                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="120" width="359" height="447"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="UGW-Gc-H5B">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="359" height="447"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" scrollEnabled="NO" text="This is the UITextView" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wad-lw-VgC">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="319" height="45"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99942404029999998" green="0.98555368190000003" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                            </textView>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.52747867609999999" green="1" blue="0.55622484120000004" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="wad-lw-VgC" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="43l-VA-TfK"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="wad-lw-VgC" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="UGW-Gc-H5B" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="6gx-L4-rfK"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="wad-lw-VgC" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="Hze-tT-ctt"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="wad-lw-VgC" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="UGW-Gc-H5B" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="O7m-RX-NHL"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.46202266219999999" green="0.83828371759999998" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="UGW-Gc-H5B" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="gBx-Cd-lhB" secondAttribute="top" id="9Ca-8i-QSo"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="UGW-Gc-H5B" secondAttribute="trailing" id="HpF-K7-pGb"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="UGW-Gc-H5B" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="gBx-Cd-lhB" secondAttribute="width" id="T85-Nb-vFG"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="UGW-Gc-H5B" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="gBx-Cd-lhB" secondAttribute="leading" id="aKi-pE-7nq"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="UGW-Gc-H5B" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="gBx-Cd-lhB" secondAttribute="height" priority="250" id="gMZ-MY-cZ4"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="UGW-Gc-H5B" secondAttribute="bottom" id="yBi-9n-Sd3"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="gBx-Cd-lhB" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="1Le-6E-02N" secondAttribute="top" constant="100" id="IpO-b2-zbv"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="1Le-6E-02N" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="gBx-Cd-lhB" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="XVi-7E-3hn"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="gBx-Cd-lhB" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="1Le-6E-02N" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="at7-bP-fws"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="1Le-6E-02N" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="gBx-Cd-lhB" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="100" id="nhL-ST-z4d"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="1Le-6E-02N"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="6C7-lr-bGI" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="136.80000000000001" y="124.58770614692655"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```